# Closing the stage from JavaFX FXML controller class (ConfirmBox)

Tags: java, javafx, controller, fxml

I'm a beginner in JavaFX, and I am developing a simple app and need to create a confirm box for closing the stage. I have done it without a problem without FXML when I have in the same method the initializing and the closing of the stage. But when I do it with FXML, when I have opened the stage in another class it fails to close it from controller class, even if I create a global stage instance.

```java
public class ConfirmBox {

    private Stage confirmBoxStage = new Stage();
    boolean confirmClose;


    // Confirm box -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    public boolean confirmClose() {

        Parent rootConfirmBox = null;

        confirmBoxStage.initModality(Modality.APPLICATION_MODAL);



        try {
            rootConfirmBox = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("ConfirmBox.fxml"));;
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.println("Exception ConfirmBox.java//confirmBoxScene");
            e.printStackTrace();
        }


        Scene confirmBoxScene = new Scene(rootConfirmBox, 640, 480);
        confirmBoxStage.setScene(confirmBoxScene);
        confirmBoxStage.showAndWait();

        return confirmClose;
    }

    // Closing the confirm box -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    public void closeConfirmBox() {
        confirmBoxStage.close();
    }

}
```

Comment: Sorry, i almost forgot, the method closeConfirmBox is accessed from the controller class, and it has access, because i tried to add a console string to it and it worked, but the stage stayed opened...

Comment: Ok, for those, who have the same problem, create a global and !static! stage instance, and it should work... the static stage is the key...